# The topologies induced by two equivalent norms are the same

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Definition:

Assume that $V$ is a vector space and two norms $||.||$ and $||.||'$ are defined on $V$.  We say $||.||$ and $||.||'$ are equivalent if there exist $M,m \gt 0$ such that:
$\forall x \in V \space\space m||x||\le ||x||' \le M||x||$

---

> Question:
>
> Assume that $V$ is an arbitrary vector space (not necessarily of
>   finite dimension) and $||.||$ and $||.||'$ are two equivalent norms on
>   it.
>
> Prove that $A \subseteq V$ is open with respect to $||.||$ iff its
>   open with respect to $||.||'$.  Finally, Conclude that the topology
>   induced by $||.||$ is the same as the one induced by $||.||'$.

My problem:

I don't know what a topology is and how to show that a set is open.  Our teacher didn't define these two and assumed that we've learned them in other courses. So, I can't even get started. Any idea? help?

Comment: If you don't know what topology is, then you need to learn topology before you answer this question...

Comment: Are you referring to the induced metric topologies?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I think that's true...

Comment: @5xum I Agree with you... but anyway, this is my situation. Isn't there a way to briefly learn just what is needed for solving this question? If u can, please just answer the question and i'll learn whatever is needed for understanding your answer. I don't want a topology course written in an answer :)

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade You might not be familiar with topologies, but you are with "open sets", right? If not then a part of my answer can be looked at as a definition of open sets. From now on just keep in mind that the topology on a space is just the collection of open sets. In my answer I avoid the term topology delibaretely.

Comment: @drhab Thanks sir :) Its a huge help :) I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is open with respect to $||.||$ if for every $a\in A$ there is some $r_a>0$ such that $\{x\mid ||x-a||<r_a\}\subseteq A$.

Now observe that $||x-a||'<r_am\implies ||x-a||<r_a$ so that

$\{x\mid ||x-a||'<mr_a\}\subseteq\{x\mid ||x-a||<r_a\}\subseteq A$ for every $a\in A$.

And we conclude that $A$ is open with respect to $||.||'$ also.

The relation on norms is an equivalence relation so also the opposite is true.

Comment: would u please explain the observation u mentioned? I'm struggling with myself to solve it but i can't understand how u reached it.

Comment: I made (wrongly) my observation on base of $||x||\leq M||x||'$. Sorry for the confusion I caused

Comment: So abusively switched accent sign. The answer is repaired now.